# Data extraction using imacros

Tags: web-scraping, imacros, extract

I need to have a imacros script to extract all data from this website 
http://www.gibsondunn.com/Search/Pages/LawyersSearch.aspx?k=('Last Name'~A*).
I manually click on alphabet link and count the result then input on max loop to play loop but its really time consuming doing that way and try to find on Google but there is no luck and try to find here. Hope there's someone help me with this.

Here also the script I create through record imacros.

```
VERSION BUILD=8871104 RECORDER=FX
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 20
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

TAB T=1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:/lawyers/* EXTRACT=HREF
TAB OPEN NEW
TAB T=2
URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
WAIT SECONDS=2

'data text
SET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=CLASS:gd_title EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=4 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=13 TYPE=DIV ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=15 TYPE=DIV ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=19 TYPE=DIV ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=20 TYPE=DIV ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=21 TYPE=DIV ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT 
TAG POS=22 TYPE=DIV ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=23 TYPE=DIV ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=gibsondunn.csv

tab close
TAB T=1
```

Really appreciate your help .

Answer (score 0):

Without using JavaScript Scripting Interface, the simplest way facilitating your task is to get rid of counting the number of lines you have to extract. Below the code that prompts it. Write down this macro in a separate .iim-file and, of course, input the obtained value manually on max loop before running your own one.

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO=javascript:{var<SP>els=window.document.getElementsByTagName("td");var<SP>n=0;for(i=0;i<els.length;i++){if(els[i].className=="gd_nameColumnData")n++}n;}
URL GOTO=javascript:{window.history.back()}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
BACK
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```